# Where do I find a find list of Node substitution variables?

Tags: node.js, electron

are there substitution variables other than `${workspaceRoot}` that can be used in the `launch.json` file?   Need a substitution variable that contains the home directory of the user.  Something like `${homePath}`.

Specifically, I need the directory path in which electron is installed using the -g option of `npm install`.

```
"configurations": [
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Electron Main",
  "runtimeExecutable": "${homePath}/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
  "protocol": "auto"
},
```

is there a document which documents all of the node builtin substitution variables?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a document which documents all of the node builtin
>   substitution variables?

There is some information about [Variable Substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_variable-substitution) on the page [Debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

Apparently, environment variables can be referenced through `${env:Name}` syntax, but some of them are definitely platform-dependent.

You may try `${env:HOME}` and see if it is what you need...

Comment: that did it!
${env:HOMEPATH}
(On the windows cmd.exe command prompt I type "set" to get a list of all the env variables.)